# Is it possible to make text bold in a custom label?

Tags: customlabel, formatting

### Background

We have a custom application which we need to support in multiple languages. Visualforce is our main UI framework.

For internationalization we will use Custom Labels. One of the possible formats we would like to use is as follows:

> "**Admin** sent **file1.pdf** to the following recipients:"

Note that `Admin` and `file1.pdf` should be bold.

I tried creating a custom label with value:

[image]

And the result is kind of "expected":

[image]

### Question

Is it possible, if at all, to use Custom Labels and format part of its text in bold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're displaying it in Visualforce maybe try something like:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!label}" escape="false"/>
```

An alternative would be to create multiple labels for the different parts of the string and then manually bold them yourself.

For instance you'd have labels for the following text:

- sent
- to the following recipients:

Then output the text in chucnks:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!userName}" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
<apex:outputText value="{!label1}"><apex:outputtext value="{!fileName}" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
<apex:outputText value="{!label2}"/>
```

My concern here would be translation as it would be seen as two seperate... sentences? which could create issues in grammar.

Comment: @Eduard But, a word of caution, make sure you escape any user input values to avoid script injection attacks.

Comment: @sfdcfox, thanks for your comment. I was also thinking that `escape="false"` might not be a really good option, but is there an alternative? Also could you please provide an example in which script injection attack would be possible in my case. I am honestly struggling with figuring this out.

Comment: It would depend on where you're getting the username and the file name. If you fill them yourself in the code it's probably fine but if you're getting them from the end user you could run into an issue (based on the little information your post offers I don't think it'd be a big concern). I think it would also depend on the audience. If it's internal users its probably a much smaller concern than if you were exposing the page via a community.

Comment: Updated to provide an alternative, although, I'm not sure if it's any better.

Comment: Thanks @gNerb. In my case the input for  `apex:outputText`'s value parameter will be the custom label, for example `<apex:outputText value="{! $Label.Paragraph_Text }" escape="false">`. I don't think someone inside the org would change a custom label with a malicious intent making script injection possible.

Comment: The question is where are you getting the admin name and the file name. If someone uploaded a file with a malicious name that could result in an injection. That being said there are usually limits on file names that would prevent something like this but that's the kind of idea I think SFDCFox was trying to get at.

Comment: Got your point. I will definitely think about this. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

To add to @gNerb's answer, the [JSINHTMLENCODE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) Visualforce expression function can be used to prevent potential script injections.

Instead of writing this:

```
<apex:outputText value="{! $Label.PARAGRAPH_SENT_TO_RECIPIENTS }" escape="false">
    <apex:param value="{! document.SubmitterName }"/>
    <apex:param value="{! document.Name }"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

which results in:

[image]

**We can write this:**

```
<apex:outputText value="{! $Label.PARAGRAPH_SENT_TO_RECIPIENTS }" escape="false">
    <apex:param value="{! JSINHTMLENCODE(document.SubmitterName) }"/>
    <apex:param value="{! JSINHTMLENCODE(document.Name) }"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

and have malicious injections knocked out:

[image]